# DataTables TableTools Rails: Issue with JavaScript Initialisation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datatables, tabletools

I have DataTables working on a Rails 3.2.13 app.This works

```
  $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#products').dataTable();
  } );
```

But, when I try adding the TableTools add-on, DataTables no longer works when adding the 'sDom' parameter:

```
  $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#products').dataTable({
       "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip'
    });
  } );
```

I added these gems:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'


# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Here are css files:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 *= require dataTables/extras/TableTools
 *= require dataTables/extras/TableTools_JUI
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Here are the js files:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/extras/TableTools
//= require_tree .
```

UPDATE:
It seems there has been an update to how to add TableTools.  You can find the update here:
https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails/pull/28

Basically I had to update the application.js file to include ZeroClipboard. (Youll also need some other files if you are using the JQueryUI)

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/extras/TableTools
//= require dataTables/extras/ZeroClipboard
```

Comment: I found the answer here: https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails/pull/28 (UPDATE INCLUDED IN THE ABOVE QUESTION).

Comment: JakeTy, please don't put your answer in the question, add as an answer.